# Show that $H_n(C_f)=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, vector-spaces, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $C=\{(C_n,\partial_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ and $C'=\{(C_n',\partial_n')\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be chain complexes of vector spaces. Let $f:C\to C'$ be a chain map. Define a new chain complex $C_f=\{(D_n,\overline{\partial}_n)\}$ as follows:

$D_n=C_{n-1}\oplus C_n'$

$\overline{\partial}_n(x,y)=(-\partial_{n-1}(x),\partial_n'(y)+f_{n-1}(x)).$

I've been proposed the following exercise:

> If $f_*:H_n(C)\to H_n(C')$ is an isomorphism, then $H_n(C_f)=0$.

What I've done so far:

Let $[(x,y)]\in H_n(C_f)$. I will try to show that $[(x,y)]=[(0,0)]$ by showing that there exists $(c_1,c_2)\in C_n\oplus C_{n+1}'$ such that $\overline{\partial}_{n+1}(c_1,c_2)=(x,y)$.

By definition, $\overline{\partial}(x,y)=(-\partial_{n-1}(x),\partial_n'(y)+f_{n-1}(x))=(0,0)$. From this, I get $\partial_{n-1}(x)=0$, so $x\in Z_{n-1}(C)$ ($x$ is a cycle in $C$) and it makes sense to consider its homology class. On the other hand, from the second component I get

$[0]=[-\partial_n'(y)]=[f_{n-1}(x)]=f_*[x].$

Since $f_*$ is isomorphism, this implies $[x]=[0]$ and hence $x\in B_{n-1}(C)$ ($x$ is a boundary), which implies that there exists $c_1\in C_n$ such that $-\partial_n(c_1)=x$.

---

Now I've got left to find $c_2\in C_{n+1}'$ such that $y=\partial_{n+1}'(c_2)+f_n(c_1)$. I haven't still used the surjectivity of $f_*$, but I don't know how to use it since in general $y$ does not define a homology class.

How can I find $c_2$?

Comment: Do you know about the long exact sequence of a SEC of complexes?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff yes I do, how can I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What underlies this problem is the long homology exact sequence associated to a short exact sequence of complexes, which I will explain.

As in your set-up, let $f: C\to C'$ be a map of complexes, and let $\text{cone}(f)$ denote the cone of the map, which you already explained how to construct. There is a short exact sequence of complexes

$$\tag 10\to C'\to \text{cone}(f) \to C[-1]\to 0$$

where the maps are the usual inclusion and projection.

*Claim* The connecting map $H(C[-1])= H(C)[-1] \to H(C')[-1]$ is the map induced by homology by $f$.

*Proof*. Suppose that $c\in C[-1]$ is a cycle. You can lift this to $(0,c)$, which has differential $(f(c),0)$. This certainly lifts to $f(c)$ in $C'$, so the snake lemma produces the map $[c]\to [f(c)]$, which is precisely $f_*$.

Now you can look at the LES of $(1)$ to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this "by hand".

Suppose that $(c,c')$ represents a cycle in the cone. You want to find $(b,b')$ such that $d(b,b') = (f(b')-db,db') = (c,c')$.

Since $(c,c')$ is a cycle, $dc = f(c')$ and $dc'=0$. Note then that in particular $c'$ represents a cycle and $f(c')$ represents a boundary. Since $f$ induces an isomorphism in homology, this means that $c'$ must be a boundary, that is, $c' = db''$, so we have solved for the second coordinate. (Almost, in fact!)

Note, moreover, that $a = c-f(b'')$ is such that $da= dc-f(db'') = dc-f(c')=0$, that is, it is a cycle in $C'$. Since $f_*$ is onto, this means there is a cycle $a'$ and some $b$ such that $f(a')-db = c-f(b'')$.

Finally, note that $c' = d(b''+a')$ since $a'$ is a cycle, and that $f(a'+b'')-db = c$. Thus $d(b,a'+b'') = (c,c')$, as you wanted.

Comment: I liked more your other answer, but I wasn't supposed to use the Snake Lemma since it hasn't been seen in class. Therefore this one is more useful to me. Anyways, which one do you prefer to be accepted?

Comment: @Javi Which question you accept is not really relevant. However, how did you prove the existence of the LES *without* the Snake Lemma?

Comment: Explicitly defining the connecting map. In the exercises, we show the Snake Lemma as a consecquence of the LES.

Comment: @Javi Well, they are equivalent results, anyways!